# Flask_admin Value from nested JSON object in column_list

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm not sure if the following is a bug/not implemented.

Following situation:

I have the following json snippet in my MongoDB:

```
[{
"firstname": "Test",
"surname": "Test",
"email_address": "example@example.com",
"country": "Austria",
"holiday_home": {
    "address": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "",
    "country": "Germany",
    "postal_code": "",
    "state_province": ""
}
}]
```

I managed to display the "first level values" (firstname, surname, email, country) in a "standard view" like this without any issues:

```
class RegistrantView(ModelView):
column_list = ('firstname', 'surname', 'email_address', 'country')
form = RegistrantForm
```

Unfortunately I do not manage to access the key/values stored nested in "holiday_home".

I've tried numerous ways, like `column_list = ([holiday_home]['country'])` but unfortunately didn't succeed.

Hence I'd like to ask if this is even possible using flask-admin with pymongo.

Comment: You can look into [column formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691462/custom-list-view-with-flask-admin)

Comment: Could u please add more information

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but as for now, there seems to be no way to do what is requested directly from a PyMongo ModelView. This means, there is no special notation allowing you to get the value from a nested document by default.

That being said, I just shared two solutions on this very specific issue here :
https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1585

First you can duplicate/override : _get_field_value function in your flask_admin_custom.contrib.pymongo.views so that it handles dotted notation better like "holiday_home.country". A proposal is :

```
def _get_field_value(self, model, name):
        """
            Get unformatted field value from the model
        """
        try:
            return reduce(dict.get, name.split('.'), model)
        except AttributeError:
            return model.get(name)
```

If you don't feel like it is a good idea at all to diverge from official Flask admin code, you can still use a column formatter as pointed by Joost.
To do so, just add a custom name in your column list:

```
column_list = ("firstname","surname", "email_address" "country")
```

Then catch this exact name in your column formatter :

```
column_formatter = {
  'country' : _country_formatter
}
```

Not forgetting to define your formatting function somewhere in your code like :

```
def _country_formatter(view, context, model, name):
  return model['holyday_home']['country']
```

That's it!

Second solution sounds more like a hack, but I think this is the way this currently done by most people.